# Error con constraint

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Practica3;
CREATE DATABASE Practica3;
USE Practica3;

CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS (
    dni VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    direcc VARCHAR(25),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20),
    codPostal VARCHAR(5),
    sexo VARCHAR(2),
    fecha_nac DATETIME,
    CHECK (sexo='h' 'm')
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS (
    dptoCod INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_dpto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    jefe VARCHAR(10),
    presupuesto INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_jefe FOREIGN KEY (jefe)
        REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(dni)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (nombre_dpto)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE UNIVERSIDADES (
    univ_cod VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_univ VARCHAR(25),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20),
    cod_postal VARCHAR(5)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE ESTUDIOS (
        dni_empleado VARCHAR(10),
        numero INT PRIMARY KEY,
        universidad VARCHAR(10),
        titulacion VARCHAR(30),
        especialidad VARCHAR(20),
        anio INT,
        CONSTRAINT fk_dni_empleado FOREIGN KEY (dni_empleado)
                REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(dni)
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT fk_universidad FOREIGN KEY (universidad)
                REFERENCES UNIVERSIDADES(univ_cod)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE TRABAJOS (
    codigo VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    salario DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (salario<5000),
    UNIQUE (nombre)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE HISTORIAL_LABORAL (
    Dni_emple VARCHAR(10),
    Trabajo_cod VARCHAR(5),
    fecha_inicio DATETIME PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_fin DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Dni_emple FOREIGN KEY (Dni_emple)
        REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(dni)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Trabajo_cod FOREIGN KEY (Trabajo_cod)
        REFERENCES TRABAJOS(codigo)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=innodb;

SHOW DATABASES;
SHOW TABLES;

SHOW CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE ESTUDIOS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE HISTORIAL_LABORAL;
SHOW CREATE TABLE UNIVERSIDADES;
SHOW CREATE TABLE TRABAJOS;
```

En la cual quiero hacer una serie de modificaciones ademas de que quiero añadir valores, para ello tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
SOURCE /home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/Practica3.sql
ALTER TABLE UNIVERSIDADES MODIFY nombre_univ VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE UNIVERSIDADES MODIFY ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE UNIVERSIDADES MODIFY cod_postal VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY direcc VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY codPostal VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY sexo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY fecha_nac DATETIME NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS MODIFY presupuesto DOUBLE(8,2);

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac)
VALUES ('1234567B', 'Antonio', 'Martin', 'Sosa', 'Calle Angel de Guadalupe', '01382', 'h', 24/12/2002);

INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (nombre_dpto, jefe, presupuesto)
VALUES ('caja', '1234567B', '20');

INSERT INTO UNIVERSIDADES (univ_cod, nombre_univ, ciudad, cod_postal)
VALUES ('1', 'uni extremadura', 'Badajoz', '123');

INSERT INTO ESTUDIOS (dni_empleado, numero, universidad, titulacion, especialidad, anio)
VALUES ('1234567B', '2', '1', 'programacion', 'java', '2020');

INSERT INTO TRABAJOS (codigo, nombre, salario)
VALUES ('1', 'teleoperador', '100,2');

INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_LABORAL (Dni_emple, Trabajo_cod, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin)
VALUES ('1234567B', '1', 15/1/2020, 15/4/2020);

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac)
VALUES ('1234567C', 'Antoni', 'Marti', 'Sos', 'Calle Angel de Guadalup','0138','h', 24/12/2001);

INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (nombre_dpto, jefe, presupuesto)
VALUES ('caj', '1234567C', '205');

INSERT INTO UNIVERSIDADES (univ_cod, nombre_univ, ciudad, cod_postal)
VALUES ('2', 'uni extremadur', 'Bada', '2020');

INSERT INTO ESTUDIOS (dni_empleado, numero, universidad, titulacion, especialidad, anio)
VALUES ('1234567C', '2', '2', 'programacion', 'java', '2020');

INSERT INTO TRABAJOS (codigo, nombre, salario)
VALUES ('2','teleoperado', '100,4');

INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_LABORAL (Dni_emple, Trabajo_cod, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin)
VALUES ('1234567C', '2', 15/1/2019, 15/4/2019);

INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (jefe)
VALUES ('123456666a');
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS ADD Valoracion VARCHAR ('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10') DEFAULT '5';
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, ciudad, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac)
VALUES ('1234567C', 'Atonio', 'Mrtin', 'Ssa', 'Cae Angel de Guadalupe','Badajoz', '0132','h', 24/12/2002);
ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS DROP UNIQUE (nombre_dpto);
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS CHANGE direcc VARCHAR(25) NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS CHANGE Valoracion VARCHAR ('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10') DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY fecha_nac VARCHAR(30);
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS ADD Telefono VARCHAR(11);
SHOW CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS;
SHOW CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS;
```

A la hora de ejecutar la base de datos se crea sin problemas pero el primer error que tengo es que cuando voy a introducir registros tengo un problema con el constraint de las claves foráneas que tienen como referencia el campo "dni" de la tabla EMPLEADOS, tambien me da algunos errores de sintaxis que desconozco dejo la salida de la ejecucion:

```
ERROR 4025 (23000) at line 11 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `Practica3`.`EMPLEADOS`
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 14 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Practica3`.`DEPARTAMENTOS`, CONSTRAINT `fk_jefe` FOREIGN KEY (`jefe`) REFERENCES `EMPLEADOS` (`dni`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,006 sec)

ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 20 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Practica3`.`ESTUDIOS`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dni_empleado` FOREIGN KEY (`dni_empleado`) REFERENCES `EMPLEADOS` (`dni`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ERROR 1265 (01000) at line 23 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Data truncated for column 'salario' at row 1
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 26 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Practica3`.`HISTORIAL_LABORAL`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Dni_emple` FOREIGN KEY (`Dni_emple`) REFERENCES `EMPLEADOS` (`dni`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ERROR 4025 (23000) at line 29 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `Practica3`.`EMPLEADOS`
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 32 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Practica3`.`DEPARTAMENTOS`, CONSTRAINT `fk_jefe` FOREIGN KEY (`jefe`) REFERENCES `EMPLEADOS` (`dni`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,016 sec)

ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 38 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Practica3`.`ESTUDIOS`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dni_empleado` FOREIGN KEY (`dni_empleado`) REFERENCES `EMPLEADOS` (`dni`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ERROR 1265 (01000) at line 41 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Data truncated for column 'salario' at row 1
ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 44 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Practica3`.`HISTORIAL_LABORAL`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Dni_emple` FOREIGN KEY (`Dni_emple`) REFERENCES `EMPLEADOS` (`dni`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
ERROR 1364 (HY000) at line 47 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': Field 'nombre_dpto' doesn't have a default value
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,073 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 50 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10') DEFAULT '5'' at line 1
ERROR 4025 (23000) at line 51 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `Practica3`.`EMPLEADOS`
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 53 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE (nombre_dpto)' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 54 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(25) NULL' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 55 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/MartinSosa_Antonio_Ejer_P3.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR ('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10') DEFAULT NULL' at line 1
```

Me gustaría saber porque me da esos errores ya que he probado a en el constraint poner ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION en lugar de CASCADE y aun así seguía dando el mismo error llevo como 2 horas buscando y no acabo de saber porque, tambien adjunto las fotos del pdf que tenemos que seguir ya que esto es un ejercicio de clase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código está plagado de errores, voy a tratar de enumerarlos:

1. La restricción `CHECK` está mal definida, debes ponerla de este modo: `CHECK (sexo='h' or sexo='m')`
2. Si `salario` aceptará valores de cuatro cifras, debes declararla como `salario DECIMAL(6,2)`, aquí el `6` indicaría *6 dígitos, de los cuales `2` son decimales*
3. Los valores para columnas del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` deben ser puestos entre comillas y en formato año, mes y día, algo así por ejemplo: `'2002/12/24'`
4. No pongas los valores decimales entre comillas
5. Este `INSERT` en la tabla `DEPARTAMENTOS`: `INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (jefe) VALUES ('123456666a');` produce error, porque estás omitiendo un valor explícito para la columna `nombre_dpto` y ésta no tiene definido un valor por defecto. Cuando se omite una columna ésta asumirá su valor por defecto. Entonces: o indicas un valor por defecto en el `CREATE TABLE` o indicas un valor para esa columna en el `INSERT INTO`. Por otro lado, siempre en ese `INSERT`, se estaría violando la restricción de integridad referencial, pues intentas insertar un `dni` con valor `123456666a` pero el mismo no existe en la tabla `EMPLEADOS`
6. En la tabla `ESTUDIOS` estás violando la PRIMARY KEY al querer insertar dos veces el valor `2` para la columna `numero`
7. La instrucción `ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;` es problemática, si `ciudad` tiene valores nulos dará error, por tanto, antes de ejecutarla deberás actualizar los posibles nulos en ese columna con un valor en blanco o algo así: `UPDATE EMPLEADOS SET ciudad='' WHERE ciudad IS NULL;`
8. Esta instrucción `ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS ADD Valoracion VARCHAR ('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10') DEFAULT '5';` no tiene ningún sentido, supongo que querrás declarar una columna del tipo `ENUM`, y te estás comiendo las comas entre cada valor, NO valga la redundancia!!!
9. Esta instrucción `INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, ciudad, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac) VALUES ('1234567C', 'Atonio', 'Mrtin', 'Ssa', 'Cae Angel de Guadalupe','Badajoz', '0132','h', 24/12/2002);` viola la restricción de `dni` único y la fecha está en formato incorrecto, como ya dije en (3).
10. La instrucción `ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS DROP UNIQUE (nombre_dpto);` es incorrecta, para borrar un índice cualquiera sólo tienes que indicar el nombre del mismo precedido de `INDEX`, sin indicar de qué tipo es, o sea: `ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS DROP INDEX nombre_dpto;`
11. No queda claro el sentido de esta instrucción: `ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS CHANGE direcc VARCHAR(25) NULL;`, se usa `CHANGE` cuando quieres cambiar el nombre de la columna, la sintaxis sería `CHANGE antiguoNombre nuevoNombre` si no es el caso, usa `MODIFY`, en cuanto al `NULL`, supongo que querrás asignarlo como valor por defecto ¿? en ese caso debes poner `DEFAULT NULL`
12. La instrucción `ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS CHANGE Valoracion VARCHAR ('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10') DEFAULT NULL;` tiene el mismo problema que ya expuse en (8), supongo que quieres definir un `ENUM` y te vuelves a comer las comas NO valga la redundancia!!! Y ocurre, en cuanto a `CHANGE` lo que te acabo de decir en (11), si no vas a cambiar el nombre de la columna realmente, no uses `CHANGE`

Como consejo, cuando estés haciendo ejercicios de este nivel de complejidad, coloca los `INSERT INTO` en orden, los de cada tabla juntos, así podrás verificar con facilidad errores de claves duplicadas o de violación de restricciones (como los descritos en los puntos 5 y 6), al estar dispersos es complicado encontrar ese tipo de errores.

Finalmente, revisa la documentación de todas las sentencias que uses: `ALTER TABLE`, `CHANGE`, `MODIFY`, etc, así como de los tipos de datos, son demasiados errores los que has cometido, signo de que has entrado al trapo, sin leer la documentación.

Aquí te dejo tu código funcionando, con todos los errores corregidos:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOS (
    dni VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    direcc VARCHAR(25),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20),
    codPostal VARCHAR(5),
    sexo VARCHAR(2),
    fecha_nac DATETIME,
    CHECK (sexo='h' or sexo='m')
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS (
    dptoCod INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_dpto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    jefe VARCHAR(10),
    presupuesto INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_jefe FOREIGN KEY (jefe)
        REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(dni)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (nombre_dpto)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE UNIVERSIDADES (
    univ_cod VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_univ VARCHAR(25),
    ciudad VARCHAR(20),
    cod_postal VARCHAR(5)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE ESTUDIOS (
        dni_empleado VARCHAR(10),
        numero INT PRIMARY KEY,
        universidad VARCHAR(10),
        titulacion VARCHAR(30),
        especialidad VARCHAR(20),
        anio INT,
        CONSTRAINT fk_dni_empleado FOREIGN KEY (dni_empleado)
                REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(dni)
                ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT fk_universidad FOREIGN KEY (universidad)
                REFERENCES UNIVERSIDADES(univ_cod)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE TRABAJOS (
    codigo VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    salario DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (salario<5000),
    UNIQUE (nombre)
) ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE HISTORIAL_LABORAL (
    Dni_emple VARCHAR(10),
    Trabajo_cod VARCHAR(5),
    fecha_inicio DATETIME PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_fin DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Dni_emple FOREIGN KEY (Dni_emple)
        REFERENCES EMPLEADOS(dni)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Trabajo_cod FOREIGN KEY (Trabajo_cod)
        REFERENCES TRABAJOS(codigo)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=innodb;

ALTER TABLE UNIVERSIDADES MODIFY nombre_univ VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE UNIVERSIDADES MODIFY ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE UNIVERSIDADES MODIFY cod_postal VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY direcc VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY codPostal VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY sexo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY fecha_nac DATETIME NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS MODIFY presupuesto DOUBLE(8,2);

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac) VALUES ('1234567B', 'Antonio', 'Martin', 'Sosa', 'Calle Angel de Guadalupe', '01382', 'h', '2002/12/24');

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac) VALUES ('1234567C', 'Antoni', 'Marti', 'Sos', 'Calle Angel de Guadalup','0138','h', '2001/12/24');

INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (nombre_dpto, jefe, presupuesto) VALUES ('caja', '1234567B', '20');
INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (nombre_dpto, jefe, presupuesto) VALUES ('caj', '1234567C', '205');
INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTOS (nombre_dpto,jefe) VALUES ('caja2','1234567B');

INSERT INTO UNIVERSIDADES (univ_cod, nombre_univ, ciudad, cod_postal) VALUES ('1', 'uni extremadura', 'Badajoz', '123');
INSERT INTO UNIVERSIDADES (univ_cod, nombre_univ, ciudad, cod_postal) VALUES ('2', 'uni extremadur', 'Bada', '2020');

INSERT INTO ESTUDIOS (dni_empleado, numero, universidad, titulacion, especialidad, anio) VALUES ('1234567B', '1', '1', 'programacion', 'java', '2020');
 INSERT INTO ESTUDIOS (dni_empleado, numero, universidad, titulacion, especialidad, anio) VALUES ('1234567C', '2', '2', 'programacion', 'java', '2020');

INSERT INTO TRABAJOS (codigo, nombre, salario) VALUES ('1', 'teleoperador', 100.2);
INSERT INTO TRABAJOS (codigo, nombre, salario) VALUES ('2','teleoperado', 100.4);

INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_LABORAL (Dni_emple, Trabajo_cod, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin) VALUES ('1234567B', '1', '2020/01/15', '2020/04/15');

INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_LABORAL (Dni_emple, Trabajo_cod, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin) VALUES ('1234567C', '2', '2019/01/15', '2019/04/15');

UPDATE EMPLEADOS SET ciudad='' WHERE ciudad IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS ADD Valoracion ENUM ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') DEFAULT '5';
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (dni, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direcc, ciudad, codPostal, sexo, fecha_nac) VALUES ('1234567D', 'Atonio', 'Mrtin', 'Ssa', 'Cae Angel de Guadalupe','Badajoz', '0132','h', '2002/12/24');
ALTER TABLE DEPARTAMENTOS DROP  INDEX nombre_dpto;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS CHANGE direcc direcc VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS CHANGE Valoracion Valoracion ENUM ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS MODIFY fecha_nac VARCHAR(30);
ALTER TABLE EMPLEADOS ADD Telefono VARCHAR(11);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLEADOS;
```

| dni | nombre | apellido1 | apellido2 | direcc | ciudad | codPostal | sexo | fecha_nac | Valoracion | Telefono |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567B | Antonio | Martin | Sosa | Calle Angel de Guadalupe |  | 01382 | h | 2002-12-24 00:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 1234567C | Antoni | Marti | Sos | Calle Angel de Guadalup |  | 0138 | h | 2001-12-24 00:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 1234567D | Atonio | Mrtin | Ssa | Cae Angel de Guadalupe | Badajoz | 0132 | h | 2002-12-24 00:00:00 | 5 |  |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM DEPARTAMENTOS;
```

| dptoCod | nombre_dpto | jefe | presupuesto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | caja | 1234567B | 20 |
| 2 | caj | 1234567C | 205 |
| 3 | caja2 | 1234567B |  |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLEADOS;
```

| dni | nombre | apellido1 | apellido2 | direcc | ciudad | codPostal | sexo | fecha_nac | Valoracion | Telefono |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567B | Antonio | Martin | Sosa | Calle Angel de Guadalupe |  | 01382 | h | 2002-12-24 00:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 1234567C | Antoni | Marti | Sos | Calle Angel de Guadalup |  | 0138 | h | 2001-12-24 00:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 1234567D | Atonio | Mrtin | Ssa | Cae Angel de Guadalupe | Badajoz | 0132 | h | 2002-12-24 00:00:00 | 5 |  |

---

**Query #4**

```
SELECT * FROM UNIVERSIDADES;
```

| univ_cod | nombre_univ | ciudad | cod_postal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uni extremadura | Badajoz | 123 |
| 2 | uni extremadur | Bada | 2020 |

---

**Query #5**

```
SELECT * FROM ESTUDIOS;
```

| dni_empleado | numero | universidad | titulacion | especialidad | anio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567B | 1 | 1 | programacion | java | 2020 |
| 1234567C | 2 | 2 | programacion | java | 2020 |

---

**Query #6**

```
SELECT * FROM TRABAJOS;
```

| codigo | nombre | salario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | teleoperador | 100.20 |
| 2 | teleoperado | 100.40 |

---

**Query #7**

```
SELECT * FROM HISTORIAL_LABORAL;
```

| Dni_emple | Trabajo_cod | fecha_inicio | fecha_fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567C | 2 | 2019-01-15 00:00:00 | 2019-04-15 00:00:00 |
| 1234567B | 1 | 2020-01-15 00:00:00 | 2020-04-15 00:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8rxCBHUP9LYjvKfFiq7Edy/1)

Comment: Corregido, muchas gracias mu amable

Comment: @Anthonyx82 me alegro de que se haya resuelto tu problema. Un cordial saludo y te recomiendo vivamente leer la documentación de cada cosa, no será jamás tiempo perdido.